# Preserving history of GIT commits while moving a GIT repository

Tags: git, history, git-commit

I have two GIT projects A and B(empty project). I want to move the entire project A into project B and preserve the history of commits while moving all the files from A to B.

What's an efficient way to do this using GIT ? I tried using git filter-branch but seems like I am not doing it the right way as it gives me "fatal...xyz/is outside repository". Could someone give some pointers ?

Thanks !

Comment: If project B is an empty project that you've just initialized with `git init`, define it as a new `remote` from project B and execute `git push -u remoteb master`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I believe, you mean new "remote" from project A ? Does this way preserve the git commit history ?

Comment: If you go in your project A repository, add a new `remote` that points to project B and then execute the above `push` command, your entire history will be preserved.

Comment: Filter branch is certainly not the right tool if you want to *preserve* something, it's rather a tool for rewriting large parts of the history.
I think Joël wanted to say "A: git remote add remoteb <urlToB>", then "A: git push -u remoteb master" (or whatever branch you want to push).

Comment: I knew about this approach but did not give it a try to actually verify if it preserves history of commits. Thanks for the suggestion everyone. I'll give this a shot.

Comment: In what sense is this an "approach"? You have a bunch of commits, you want to push them to a repository B. So you add B as remote repo and push, that's it. There are no other "approaches", as far as I can tell.

Comment: Oh I was referring to Joel's comment. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. That works. Just make sure to do a "git pull remoteb master" if you initialized the new project with a ReadMe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the complete workflow described in our question's comments.

I assume that you want to push the entire history of branch `master` from **Project A** to **Project B**.

1. **Project B folder** > Initialize the git repo:

   `git init`
2. **Project A folder** > Add Project B repo as a new remote:

   `git remote add remoteb <urlToB>`
3. **Project A folder** > Checkout the appropriate branch (if required):

   `git checkout master`
4. **Project A folder** > Push the entire history of branch `master` to `remoteb`:

   `git push -u remoteb master`

If you want additional information about the `git push` command and parameters, you can find the official documentation here: [git push Documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push)

Comment: step 1 should be `git init --bare` otherwise you may have an error like `remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master`